# MonoTouch: Adding Default-568h@2x.png for iPhone 5 Retina 4

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, iphone-5

In our `MonoTouch` projects, is adding a `Default-568h@2x.png` image, at `640 x 1136` all that is needed to support the app as is on an iPhone 5 ?

Comment: iOS6 and Xcode 4.5 are still under NDA (for a few days). In the mean time please contact support@xamarin.com if you have specific questions about them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the key change required for the OS to size the window to fill the iPhone 5 display. Redth# has posted a [writeup](http://redth.info/get-your-monotouch-apps-ready-for-iphone-5-today/) on this and other size-related tweaks you might need to make.