# iOS 6 - Handle iPhone 5 screen size without Default-568h@2x.png

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, ios6, iphone-5

We are working on a game, that renders a couple splash screens while loading.

So we are not using Default.png or Default@2x.png, because it makes sense for the screen to be blank on startup.

So how to do you get iOS 6 in the iPhone 5 simulator to render our game full screen without the splash screen image mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412063/monotouch-adding-default-568h2x-png-for-iphone-5-retina-4)?  Do we just need to think about using splash screen images?  Is it the only way?  I would think there should be something you can turn on in `Info.plist`.

We would still prefer to not use splash screen images, since it would make our app bundle larger--we are very close to 50MB.

Comment: I've not tested this but is it the presence of the Default@2x.png file that sets large screen support or the filesize?  If it is just the presence then a very small black png could be included that won't break the 50MB limit.  You will need to test this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not know if there are any other methods iOS uses to detect support for the iPhone 5 screen size, but maybe you can include a blank splash screen?

I completely black png shouldn't take up much space.

Comment: We ended up creating a real splash screen, but this works as well.

Comment: When I create a new ios 6 app there's just a black default screen...so I thunk thats ok

Answer (score 4):

If you use an empty [Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) for your Launch Images, the iPhone 5's screen size is supported (without having to include any image files at all).

Answer (score 0):

For what i know, adding this Default is the only way to handle iPhone 5 screen.
Maybe you can just add Default images that are only black

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a 568 launch image to gain full screen, and empty Launch Images option in general setting.