# Splash screen not showing in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, splash-screen

I recently updated my Xcode, now it is using iOS6. A day before in iOS5 it was working fine, but now in iOS6, it is not showing splash screen.

I just added a image named `default.png` and tried `Default.png` also, but its not working now. Can anyone guide me what is wrong here.

Comment: which code you used?? please post some code..

Comment: @ParasJoshi there is no code required to show splash screen in iphone.  Just need to add an image with specified name to the bundle. So I believe this question also doesn't requires code.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra yes i know but some time for for downloading some data , add splashscreen with coding and set time which user wants , so i just ask that which functionality not working here..

Comment: Don't u have Default@2x.png image included in the project.

Comment: Rename default to Default.png (for ios 6 Default-568h@2x.png. It should work if u are building for both iphone 4 and 5).
See this [link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512221/ios-6-handle-iphone-5-screen-size-without-default-568h2x-png)

Comment: Is Default@2x.png is right not Default.png.

Comment: give us code where you set your splashImage..

Comment: no i am not using any code just set Default.png

Comment: here what are you referring is launch image not a splash image as you are saying in the question.

Launch Image is displayed when the app loads.

Splash screen means, that you display a view with about information as your startscreen. Your User should use your app immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the apple [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html):
For apps that run on iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation) with iOS 6, create a launch image that measures `640 x 1136` pixels with the name `Default-568h@2x.png`.

Please also verify the launch image name in `info.plist` file.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to project -> summary, you can also drag in your image to the spot of your default image. Xcode will make a local copy. If it's done copying you can delete your old default image.

[image: (see screenshot below)]

Please notice that you keep yourself to the splashscreen standards.

1. Name your images Default.png, Default@2x.png & Default-568h@2x.png
2. Keep yourself to the respective sizes

   - 320 x 480
   - 640 x 960
   - 640 x 1136

Comment: `Default-568@2x.png` should be `Default-568h@2x.png`. Besides that, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with Default.png / Default@2x.png.It took me a while to find this out.
In your project check under Build Settings-Targets
COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES is set to NO